# Apply two different-sized UV maps in one shader

Tags: uv, shaders, normal-map

I have a sofa model that I use to render interiors. (sofa has 3 million polygons)
[image: Text]
I wanted to integrate it as a prop into the game, but for this I need to reduce it to 10,000 polygons. (I did this and created a normal map)
[image: Text]
The texture on the sofa is not unique and is simply duplicated (in the original).
[image: Text]
And for the normal texture map, I baked it under a uv mask.

How can I apply a different-sized uv mask to the same model, on the same polygons?
I mean, how do I increase the uv map of the texture (to improve the resolution), while not increasing the uv map of the normal map.

Comment: You can simply create a second UV map?

Comment: @lemon it is possible, but using the same polygons in two different uv maps, they increase in two maps at once. I haven't found a way to make them different sizes.

Comment: I still don't get the point: do you ask about how to have to UV maps and use them in one shader? or do you want to keep only one UV map but scale it differently when used for texture and for normal map?

Comment: @lemon I'm not sure how it works correctly, but most likely I mean the second option. One UV map, but of different sizes for normals and for texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either scale one unique UV map, like this:

[image]

Or create two UV maps, scaled differently:

[image]